# TypeError: $ is not a function - in firefox console

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, web

Getting type "TypeError: $ is not a function" when the below code is entered in firefox console. I don't know any thing about java script. can anyone fix this.

```
setInterval(function(){ $('.reserve-btn').trigger('click'); console.log('Working.. Dont press any key until we add your phone to your cart.'); },10);
```

Comment: I admire your courage and frankly admitting to not knowing anything about javascript.

Comment: I think u did't added jquey-Min or added after method declaration

Comment: First of all, `Java !== JavaScript`

Comment: the jQuery library hasn't been referenced in the document / site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in the  of your page

```
<script src="htps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks its working.. after adding above code.